# Text not staying in div, which is inside another div?

Tags: html, css

simple code, I tried various ways but I can't change position of the text inside a div which is inside another div!?

HtML:

```
<div class="left_container">

<?php 
$i=1;
while($i<=6)
{
echo "<br><div class='data_block'><img src='g.jpg' class='data_image'/><span class='.data_title'>TOPIC TITLE HERE</span></div>";    
$i++;   
}
?>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left_container
{
    background-color:;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-top:5%;
    width:70%;
    height:1000px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

.data_block
{
    background-color: white;
    width:95%;
    height:20%;
    border:solid 1px #006666;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.data_title
{
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Nevis;
    margin-left:500px;
}
```

I want to reposition the "TOPIC TITLE HERE", set left margin, keep it in center. But nothing works on it! The text is just positioned at the lower part of the div!? why?

**EDITED: the error was class=".data_title" which I corrected it but still problem is there! The text is showing outside the div now!**

Comment: Use float: left; in all your classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining class with **`.`** (dot) is not proper, it should be `class='data_title'`.

change

```
class='.data_title'
```

to

```
class='data_title'
```

You should also add `float: left` to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
class='.data_title'
```

to

```
class='data_title'  and

<div class="aleft_container">

</div>
```

You have to modify your css also i.e, change your class name.

```
.aleft_container
{
    background-color:some-color;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-top:5%;
    width:70%;
    height:1000px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

.data_block
{
    background-color: white;
    width:95%;
    height:20%;
    border:solid 1px #006666;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.data_title
{
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Nevis;
    margin-left:500px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I can only tick one answer, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Change the class name `class=".datablock"` into `class="datablock"`.

And then add your positioning code.

**EDIT**

Add `float: left;` or `display: block;` for your class styles.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I can only tick one answer, sorry